# Highstock scrollbar doesn't work in svg foreignObject

Tags: javascript, svg, highcharts

I'm using Highstock, inserting it into some `<svg>` via a `<foreignObject>` element, like so:

http://jsfiddle.net/3svXN/

However, in Firefox, the scroll bar doesn't work - and it doesn't work in my JsFiddle example either. How can I make the Highstocks scrollbar work in a SVG `<foreignObject>`?

## Edit

While the above case works in Firefox12, the following case which makes use of the [viewBox](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#ViewBoxAttribute) attribute for a zoom effect doesn't:

http://jsfiddle.net/3svXN/9/

How can I make the Highstocks scrollbar work in a SVG `<foreignObject>` while it is affected by a `viewBox` attribute?

Comment: What do you mean with "It doesn't work"?It's working for me on Chrome. MAybe i'm not getting the right way it should work

Comment: @Nicola Peluchetti - Interesting... I'm on FireFox. Perhaps that has to do with it... * tries Chrome * Damn, you're right.

Answer (score 2):

The original testcase works on Firefox trunk. This means that it should work once Firefox 13 comes out on 5th June 2012. I haven't checked Firefox 11 or 12 to see whether it's fixed any earlier than version 13 so you might get lucky earlier.

Comment: Didn't work in 11, but Aurora 12.0a2 (2012-03-05) didn't have the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think that there is a problem with the jQuery version you are using. I switched to 1.7.1 and it works on firefox and chrome (can't test it on IE)

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3svXN/3/

EDIT - actually this is quite strange: my fiddle works correctly with 1.7.1 only if you open it with firefox and press "Run” or you select a different timeframe. You should try it locally. With jQuery edge (But i think those are the nightly build) it never works

Comment: You have put the `x` and `y` coordinates on the `<svg>` element - not on the `<foreignObject>`.  Also, on my project, we're using jQuery 1.7.1 already.

Comment: @RichardJPLeGuen i'm sorry i messed up the html...in that case i think it's a browser-related issue i think.